# Android Management Api Cross-profile contact management

Tags: android-management-api

At https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements?api=clouddpx#25-wipe-and-lock it is stated that there are two flags that can be set in a policy and that affect the way contact data can leave the work profile.

The flags are “crossProfileContactsSearchDisabled” and “crossProfileCallerIdDisabled” but the links pointing to them do not show any related data.

I already submitted a product feedback.